# R ggplot add contribution as a label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am drawing a set of graphs based on Send quantity, but I want to add a label that gives me the **contribution** to the facet.

```
p = ggplot(data = dbnbuckets, aes(x=DBNBucket, y=sent)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(fill=year)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Sent", labels = comma)  + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  facet_grid(PRODUCT_TYPE_DESC~year)
```

I want to add a label per data point per chart that is the contribution of the DBNBucket to the Product type / year grouping.

Dput output:

```
structure(list(DBNBucket = c("a. 0", "a. 0", "a. 0", "a. 0", 
"a. 0", "a. 0", "a. 0", "a. 0", "b. 1-10", "b. 1-10", "b. 1-10", 
"b. 1-10", "b. 1-10", "b. 1-10", "b. 1-10", "b. 1-10", "c. 11-100", 
"c. 11-100", "c. 11-100", "c. 11-100", "c. 11-100", "c. 11-100", 
"c. 11-100", "c. 11-100", "d. 101-1000", "d. 101-1000", "d. 101-1000", 
"d. 101-1000", "d. 101-1000", "d. 101-1000", "d. 101-1000", "d. 101-1000", 
"e. 1k-10k", "e. 1k-10k", "e. 1k-10k", "e. 1k-10k", "e. 1k-10k", 
"e. 1k-10k", "e. 1k-10k", "e. 1k-10k", "f. 10k-100k", "f. 10k-100k", 
"f. 10k-100k", "f. 10k-100k", "f. 10k-100k", "f. 10k-100k", "f. 10k-100k", 
"g. 100k-1m", "g. 100k-1m", "g. 100k-1m"), year = c("2019", "2019", 
"2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2019", "2019", 
"2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2019", "2019", 
"2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2019", "2019", 
"2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2019", "2019", 
"2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2019", "2019", 
"2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2019", "2020", "2021"
), PRODUCT_TYPE_DESC = c("FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", 
"REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", 
"FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", 
"REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", 
"FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", 
"REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", 
"FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", 
"REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", 
"FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", 
"REPLENISHMENT", "FASHION", "REPLENISHMENT", "REPLENISHMENT", 
"REPLENISHMENT", "REPLENISHMENT", "REPLENISHMENT"), sent = c(6598L, 
7851L, 6655L, 11288L, 10644L, 14948L, 5945L, 9945L, 640182L, 
440539L, 564572L, 314811L, 568514L, 377454L, 298326L, 241494L, 
3487188L, 10889238L, 2608660L, 7857196L, 4758689L, 9891986L, 
2082144L, 6901459L, 44532432L, 164251950L, 37715756L, 136677537L, 
37514959L, 166775959L, 22446471L, 104088081L, 117507490L, 188990081L, 
105983150L, 169459053L, 118467830L, 191009215L, 60272548L, 119528730L, 
2066280L, 32834997L, 1654908L, 29759615L, 877615L, 26756029L, 
3631792L, 2932100L, 4533700L, 3175600L), avestores = c(1.18181818181818, 
1.78086237448317, 1.19022103148024, 4.61382650814619, 1.30058252427184, 
1.95118858954041, 1.17246273953158, 1.66666666666667, 3.31897004729375, 
12.9294335109275, 2.87502030209518, 12.511012605624, 3.80094082693736, 
12.2275666477595, 3.64528593508501, 12.4097320169252, 22.3574978577549, 
112.310084749199, 19.4699007717751, 112.913580246914, 17.531177676387, 
110.006315602206, 16.6743273542601, 108.850990131364, 297.08912910463, 
484.789001560062, 298.605569306931, 457.966536767198, 271.617478510029, 
468.440746659256, 272.7230280151, 464.853888116376, 993.624395486298, 
963.346374148925, 976.59351959643, 992.291702626063, 976.069058781104, 
997.338022165388, 930.930746068919, 994.894041921109, 1526.76923076923, 
1423.75, 1497.08333333333, 1451.59459459459, 1430.85714285714, 
1444.05755395683, 1411.56, 1314, 1490.33333333333, 1565), avesent = c(4.47625508819539, 
4.63733018310691, 4.45746818486269, 4.9704975781594, 4.13359223300971, 
4.7378763866878, 4.21930447125621, 4.86784140969163, 48.058103745965, 
47.9002935739915, 45.8479779113204, 43.6086715611581, 46.9187092514649, 
42.819512195122, 46.1091190108192, 42.5765162200282, 298.816452442159, 
441.557033372532, 287.614112458655, 451.174045363193, 314.665674799974, 
439.956680305995, 291.780269058296, 451.046271485524, 4541.34529879665, 
3768.28370193631, 4667.79158415842, 3859.63902067096, 4478.86329990449, 
3862.43217767896, 4459.85912974369, 3711.20194673227, 21047.3741715923, 
20424.7358694477, 20563.2809468374, 20892.4982123043, 21360.9502344032, 
20354.7756820119, 20164.7868852459, 19727.4682290807, 158944.615384615, 
195446.410714286, 137909, 201078.47972973, 125373.571428571, 
192489.417266187, 145271.68, 1466050, 1511233.33333333, 1587800
), dbns = c(1474L, 1693L, 1493L, 2271L, 2575L, 3155L, 1409L, 
2043L, 13321L, 9197L, 12314L, 7219L, 12117L, 8815L, 6470L, 5672L, 
11670L, 24661L, 9070L, 17415L, 15123L, 22484L, 7136L, 15301L, 
9806L, 43588L, 8080L, 35412L, 8376L, 43179L, 5033L, 28047L, 5583L, 
9253L, 5154L, 8111L, 5546L, 9384L, 2989L, 6059L, 13L, 168L, 12L, 
148L, 7L, 139L, 25L, 2L, 3L, 2L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(
    DBNBucket = c("a. 0", "a. 0", "a. 0", "a. 0", "b. 1-10", 
    "b. 1-10", "b. 1-10", "b. 1-10", "c. 11-100", "c. 11-100", 
    "c. 11-100", "c. 11-100", "d. 101-1000", "d. 101-1000", "d. 101-1000", 
    "d. 101-1000", "e. 1k-10k", "e. 1k-10k", "e. 1k-10k", "e. 1k-10k", 
    "f. 10k-100k", "f. 10k-100k", "f. 10k-100k", "f. 10k-100k", 
    "g. 100k-1m", "g. 100k-1m", "g. 100k-1m"), year = c("2019", 
    "2020", "2021", "2022", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2019", 
    "2020", "2021", "2022", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2019", 
    "2020", "2021", "2022", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2019", 
    "2020", "2021"), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 
        9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19:20, 21:22, 23:24, 
        25:26, 27:28, 29:30, 31:32, 33:34, 35:36, 37:38, 39:40, 
        41:42, 43:44, 45:46, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -27L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Stackoverflow now complains that my post is mostly code, so I'll try to add more here to get that error to die...

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Sorry, only got back to this today. Eventually inserted it manually afterwards. But I've edited the original post to include the dput data.